# Sequence contains no elements, no OpenID endpoint found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, google-signin

I'm trying to use google accounts/login for my website(it is local at the moment/localhost) but I keep getting this error. I uncommented `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();` in the AuthConfig class.

> Sequence contains no elements

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no elements

Source Error:

```
Line 362: public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
Line 363: {
Line 364:     OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
Line 365: }
```

Source File: c:\Users\JoeyM\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OdeToFood\OdeToFood\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 364

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +269
       DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier       userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +112

[ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier     userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +154
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OpenIdClient.RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl) +100
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.RequestAuthentication(String returnUrl) +377
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String provider, String returnUrl) +57
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(String provider, String returnUrl) +92
   OdeToFood.Controllers.ExternalLoginResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) in c:\Users\JoeyM\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OdeToFood\OdeToFood\Controllers\AccountController.cs:364
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651116
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: I think Google changed their API and this will not work for newer domains anyway (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780039/mvc-google-login-openid-auth-request-contains-an-unregistered-domain) - not sure if it is exactly related but maybe it's of general interest