# Google OpenID - change domain

Tags: openid, google-oauth, google-openid

Recently my company need to change domain. We are using Google OpenID, which is deprecated so I cannot add new domain (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto). We get message "OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain". Is it posible to resolve the problem without migration to new API?

Comment: No I don't think you can fix that.  I also think you are going to have issues with migrating as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a [registration request](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-federated-login-api/eIz-i1UYhQY) up-to June 15th (make sure to include a sample HTTP OpenID2 request -- the one leading to the error message).

See the discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773275/changed-domain-error-openid-auth-request-contains-an-unregistered-domain) for more context.

Regardless of the domain registration issue, I suggest to start the migration work as soon as possible (as stated in a [resent blog post](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/02/welcome-openid-connect.html), the support for Google OpenID is scheduled to end soon -- April 2015)