# Asp.Net MVC 4 use oAuth2 for google

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We are trying to enable "login with google" for an existing asp.net MVC 4 project. But now google has announced deprecation of  OpenID 2.0 and suggested to use OAuth2. We found this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) for mvc5 project. How can we do this in ASP.NET mvc 4 project? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: @Freerider we don't want to migrate to asp.net identity at this time. Can't I use oAuth2 with membership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to register new client for google oAuth in AuthConfig.cs file. Jerrie Pelser explained it [here](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/blog/google-signin-for-asp-net-mvc). Since I was looking for login with google account not google+, I just had to update scope to https://mail.google.com.

Comment: The article by Pelser works fine. Thanks for sharing the link.